# PySpark window function improvement

Tags: python, pyspark, hive, window-functions

I have requirement to replace with previous record value, So I have implemented this using window function but i want to improve performance. Could you please advise if there is any other alternative approach.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Window, DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

source = [(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(1,3,4)]
target = [(1,3,1),(3,4,1)]
schema = ['key','col1','col2']
source_df = spark.createDataFrame(source, schema=schema)
target_df = spark.createDataFrame(source, schema=schema)

df = source_df.unionAll(target_df)

window = Window.partitionBy(F.col('key')).orderBy(F.col('col2').asc())


df = df.withColumn('col1_prev', F.lag(F.col('col1_start')).over(window)\
       .withColumn('col1', F.lit('col1_next'))

df.show()
```

```
1,3,1
1,2,1
1,3,3
2,3,4
3,4,1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `last` function in a specified interval, say the last 2 rows in the window. I will set it as `maxsize` here as an example:

```
import sys
window = Window.partitionBy('key')\
               .orderBy('col2')\
               .rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, -1)

df = F.last(df['col1_prev'], ignorenulls=True).over(window)
```

I hope it could resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Amir, Does this to improve performance or to avoid nulls? i thought last will return last value depending on sorting order but i need previous record non null value

Comment: `last` function return last record (previous record) based on the order you want. You could either ignore nulls or not which is a great option in your hand. I reckon in comparison with the `lag` function, `last` should be quicker.